# In MATLAB, How I can run multiple files .m (M-file) automatically?

Tags: matlab

In [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), how I can run 20 files .m (M-file) automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "automatically"?

Answer (score 6):

Make another M-file and put all of the names of your 20 existing M-files in that.

If you want them to run on startup, put them in `startup.m` in the startup directory (see `doc startup`).

If they have systematic names, you can put the following in a loop:

```
[y1, y2, ...] = feval(function, x1, ..., xn)
```

where `function` is a string that you develop in the loop.

Edit: if the M-files are scripts rather than functions it is safer for future versions to use:

```
eval(s)
```

where `s` is the name of the script.

Answer (score 4):

There are lots of ways, depending on what behaviour you want. MATLAB is a very flexible environment for this kind of stuff. If your files are in c:\work\myTwentyFiles, create a new file "runMyFiles.m" containing

```
function runMyFiles()
myDir = 'c:\work\myTwentyFiles';

d = dir([myDir filesep '*.m']);
for jj=1:numel(d)
    try
        toRun = fullfile(myDir, d(jj).name);
        fprintf('Running "%s"', toRun);
        run(toRun)
    catch E
        % Up to you!
    end
end
```

and then use the "-r" option to make MATLAB run this file automatically:

```
matlab -r runMyFiles
```

There are many other variations -- the hard-coded location of the MATLAB files looks unattractive for starters...

Just spotted the updated question: another option is to use a cell-array of functions to call

```
d = {'myfun1','myfun2', 'myfun3'};
```

and do something similar to the example above -- you'll need to change the definition of "toRun" to something like

```
toRun = fullfile(myDir, d{jj});
```

Comment: I know this post is old, but i have a similar question and in order to avoid creating another new post, i ask it here. I have nearly same problem as @Matlabo09 but with a little difference, one of my m file use another functhion in itself so when i run above code, it would go to the said function firstly and because matlab could not run a function alone, it would give me an error and my code stop and dose not run other m files. so could you tell me how i prevent it from running the function?